# Как присвоить класс в зависимости от значения value jquery

Tags: jquery

есть код

```html
<li>
<label for="mse2_[[+table]][[+delimeter]][[+filter]]_[[+idx]]" class="[[+disabled]]">
<input type="radio" style="display:none" name="[[+filter_key]]" id="mse2_[[+table]][[+delimeter]][[+filter]]_[[+idx]]" value="actived" [[+checked]] [[+disabled]]/> [[+title]]
</label>
</li>
```

Нужно при загрузке страницы проверять значение у inputa. Если value=actived то label нужно присвоить класс active.
Как же это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно выбрать все элементы с [`value="actived"`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): `$('[value="actived"]')`
2. Для получения label, взять у полученных элементов [родителей](https://api.jquery.com/parent/): `.parent()`
3. [Добавить нужный класс](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/): `.addClass('active')`